# No route matches [GET] "/refinery"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms

I unload refinery and face to problem. When I start my server (rails server) - open the page where: No route matches [GET] "/refinery". 
I am beginner in refinery.
I am following to http://refinerycms.com/guides and create rickrockstar application.

Comment: What is the last step you did ? Could you show your routes (either the file, or just the output of "rake routes")

Answer (score 4):

Actually there's a note in the guide which warns about this specific problem:

> If you encounter a routing error afterwards, run rails generate refinery:cms —fresh-installation

If that doesn't work just recreate the app by running

```
 refinerycms rickrockstar
```